# visual basic/mysql displaying data

Tags: mysql, database, reference

We're making a program with visual basic and we have a grid, it shows data from a database.
But now there is a problem, we're displaying numbers instead of actual words, this is easy to fix with a bit of google BUT we got 2 columns with references to the same table.
So in more details, we got one table with the references, it's name is v_Transport and has an id, relationid, carrierid (those are more then enough for this example)
the data looks like this

```
1 | 803 | 503
2 | 653 | 321
```

then we have a second table called Relations with an id and name(again those are enough)

```
653 | spike
321 | google
803 | stackoverflow
503 | humbletest
```

normaly I would do something like

```
select t.id, r.name
from transport t, relations r
where r.id = t.relationid
```

This could work if there was just one reference but there are 2 to the same table. just a small thing, I can't test my query so im pretty sure it's not working or even near working.
But my question is: what would be a good way to get the data to show the right way like

```
1 | stackoverflow | humbletest
2 | spike | google
```

And if possible with an explanation of the code and possible link to a source to get more info about the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
select  t.id, r.name relation_name, rc.name carried_name
from    transport t INNER JOIN
    relations r ON r.id = t.relationid INNER JOIN
    relations rc ON rc.id = t.carrierid
```

This is way yuo join to the same reference table twice, from 2 different fields in the source table.

If you are unsure of if all the reference ids are populated, you would rathet use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select  t.id, IFNULL(r.name,'NA') relation_name, IFNULL(rc.name,'NA') carried_name
from    transport t LEFT JOIN
    relations r ON r.id = t.relationid LEFT JOIN
    relations rc ON rc.id = t.carrierid
```

Then you could also use `IFNULL` to display what you want, if you wish.

Comment: relations r ON r.id = t.relationid INNER JOIN
    relations rc ON rc.id = r.carrierid 

shouldnt the final line be relations rc ON rc.id = t.carrierid 
since the carrierid is in transport?

Comment: @knowndead, correct, sorry. I have corrected it now.